# I have created two threads but none of the thread is hitting the methods that it suppose to hit

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am learning multithreading in c# & executing all my code in IDE VS 2019. I have created two threads but none of the thread is hitting the methods that are supposed to hit (I used breakpoints as well). I have posted the code below. Please advise what I am doing wrong. Also, is this an efficient way to execute a thread? If not, suggest an efficient way.
Thanks in advance.
PS: If this question is already asked, please share the link. I googled the solution for my query, but no satisfactory answer found.

Code ->

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SayHiEnglish));
        t1.Name = "Starting method SayHiEnglish()";
        t1.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SayHiSpanish));
        t2.Name = "Starting Method SayHiSpanish()";
        t2.Start();
        //SayHiEnglish();
        //SayHiSpanish();
    }

    static void SayHiEnglish()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi in English");
        }

    }

    static void SayHiSpanish()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi in Spanish");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your program without a debugger attached? Just hit Ctrl+F5 and see if anything different happens!

Comment: Yes. I tried that too. but the program was exiting before threads start/finished. Just by adding Console.ReadLine(); before closing the main method, solved my issue because it blocked the program from exiting and provided threads some extra time to perform the action.

Comment: You haven't set the [`Thread.IsBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground) property to `true`, and the default is `false`, so the two threads should keep the program running. I am surprised that they didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with the threads itself, but your program is exiting before the threads starts/finished. So you have "block/wait" you main thread so the threads can execute.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SayHiEnglish));
        t1.Name = "Starting method SayHiEnglish()";
        t1.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SayHiSpanish));
        t2.Name = "Starting Method SayHiSpanish()";
        t2.Start();
        //SayHiEnglish();
        //SayHiSpanish();

        Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void SayHiEnglish()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi in English");
        }

    }

    static void SayHiSpanish()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi in Spanish");
        }

    }
}
```

A more modern way to use threads is the `Task.Run( () => { .. code here ...} );`, but the main thread still have to wait.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I have marked this answer as accepted since it has answered all my questions. Also, I learnt a modern way to use threads.

Comment: Frank, As suggested by you I used Task.Run(()=>{...code...});, But I think, now the methods are executing sequentially within the Task.Run block.
 Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Modern way to run Thread.");
                SayHiEnglish();
                SayHiSpanish();
            });

Comment: I solved my own issue-
By calling methods from different threads, they are now executing in non-sequential (more faster) manner.
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Modern way to run Thread.");
                
                SayHiEnglish();
            });

Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Modern way to run Thread.");
                
                SayHiSpanish();
            });

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code. It's working. Run program by pressing Ctrl+F5 to avoid the console disappear.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
StartUtility();
}
private static void StartUtility()
{
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SayHiEnglish));
thread1.Start();

Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SayHiSpanish));
thread2.Start();
}
private static void SayHiEnglish()
{
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("Hi in English");
}

}
private static void SayHiSpanish()
{
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("Hi in Spanish");
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaric. As Suggested by Frank if we use 'block/wait' statement in the main method to stop the program from exiting before the threads start/finish, then your suggested answer will give the desired output in debug (F5) mode as well.